# Live streaming video integration in C# ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, silverlight-5.0

I am going to make a website which will show me live streaming. Of course technologies are C# ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC. For testing purpose, Now I want to use my PC's webcam to shoot video and it will be displayed on the .aspx or say .cshtml page directly on the same time. So let me know what will I do? If anyone from India, just see the Saibaba Live Darshan official website and I just need to make same type of site.After successful testing,I will deploy and host this application on hosting server. There is a temple where I will integrate this system so that everyone can take live darshan on their web browsers. So please guide me how to achieve this. Tell me all possible ways and if you have complete project code,then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5/getUserMedia to capture a video stream from the users webcam.

You can then display this on a html5/canvas for the user, or if you prefer you can use WebRTC to stream it to a server.

You can also look into projects such as this one: https://code.google.com/p/telepresence/

If you prefer to implement it yourself you can look here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/cross-browser-camera-capture-with-getusermediawebrtc/

Comment: Actually I need this implementation with C# ASP.NET only,so suggest me any other proper way..

Comment: There are some solutions for that, like here: http://dathor.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/xsocketsnet-websockets-webrtc-example.html